# How to pass JSON from Spark to AngularJS in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using apache Zeppelin notebook and I need to pass JSON data from spark to AngularJS with z.AngularBind.

I have tried this using spark interpreter:

```
%spark
val test = Seq(("A","B","C"),("D","E","F"))
             .toDF("col1","col2","col3")
             .toJSON
             .collectAsList
z.angularBind("test", test)

test: Array[String] = Array({"col1":"A","col2":"B","col3":"C"}, {"col1":"D","col2":"E","col3":"F"})
```

And I would expect the output of the code below using angular inerpreter:

```
%angular
{{test[0].col1}}
```

to return **A**, but it does not because it recognizes each row of **test** as a string and not as a JSON object.

Any ideas?